# how to check all checbox on click of parent checkbox using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project where there is template which i am loading through a bootstrap modal in asp.net MVC in that modal there is a table which i am loading dynamically. There are checkboxes beside each record and on selection of every checkbox that data is getting selected. Now i want to add a parent checkbox on click of which i want to check all checkboxes from that table. I have written following code but not able to achieve the functionality.
`

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover left" style="width:100%;margin:0px;" 
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                       
                                <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 3px 0; ng-model="selectAll" 
         ng-click="checkAll()">
                                </th>
                                <th>NAME</th>
                                <th>CITY</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tr ng-repeat="clientData in Clients>

                            <td>
                               <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 3px 0;" ng-model="clientData.IsSelectedClients" ng-change="checkClients(clientData.IsSelectedClients); IsAllSelectedClient=false;"/>

                            </td>
                            <td>{{clientData.Name}}</td>
                            <td>{{agentData.City}}</td>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </table>`
```

Angular js code is below

```
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.Clients, function(client) {
      client.IsSelectedClients= $scope.selectAll;
    });
  };
```

I am not able to find out why it is not working can anybody help me to get it working
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried ng-checked?

Comment: @AmitGupta no i've not tried

Comment: Try adding attribute ng-checked="clientData.IsSelectedClients"

Comment: @AmitGupta i've tried not working

Comment: Then please confirm IsSelectedClients attribute of $scope.Clients have true value when you click on select all? Also, check what is the value of $scope.selectAll.